# cannot convert from 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'

Tags: .net, guid

Does anyone know how to deal with this error?

```
cannot convert from 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

In that case, merely use `myNullableVariable.Value` (if you're sure it has a value), or `(myNullableVariable.HasValue)?myNullableVariable.Value:somedefaulthere` if you're not.

One can also use `GetValueOrDefault()` if one doesn't care if the default is a specific value when the nullable really is null.

The last way to do it is this: `myNullableVariable.Value ?? defaultvalue`.

See, technically a `MyType?` variable is a `Nullable<MyType>` under the covers. There are no implicit or explicit casts between the two, so what you need to do is extract the value out of the `Nullable` manually. The third way i listed is the most succinct (and best?) way to do it, to that would probably be best in most cases.

Answer (score 6):

Use Guid?.Value property to convert 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'. as following example

```
Obj GetValue(Guid yourID)
{
return FetchObject(yourID)
}
Void main()
{
Guid? passvalue;
Obj test = GetValue(passvalue.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `Nullable<T>.HasValue` in if statement to check the value for null, then after it you can use `Nullable<T>.Value` to gets the value of an underlying type.

```
int? a = null;
if(a.HasValue){
  Console.WriteLine($"a has value {a.Value}");
} else {
  Console.WriteLine("No value found in a");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First intialize the guid variable.

```
Guid yourGuid= Guid.NewGuid()
```

then set value in that which you want for eg:

```
 Guid defaultId = Guid.NewGuid();
 if (customerRow.GuardianState.Length > 2) {
 Guid StateId = record.StateId ?? defaultId;}
```

Answer (score 0):

cannot convert from 'System.Guid?' to 'System.Guid'

you are trying to save type  System.Guid? to a type system.Guid
inside your model you can edit System.Guid? to System.Guid by removing the question mark.

or 
RCIX answer above

Comment: The answer was accepted 7 years ago, what new value does this bring?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure value is not null then you can cast value as a (Guid)

```
var identifier = (Guid)myOtherIdentifier!;
```

Or you can use

```
var identifier = myOtherIdentifier.HasValue ? myOtherIdentifier : Guid.Empty;
```

Or another usage is

```
var identifier = myOtherIdentifier ?? Guid.Empty;
```